# Puppeteer - Display HTML version of a javascript website on my server for scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

- I need to display the html version of website (ftmarket, morningstar..) on my server in order to **scrape** the information on it with google sheet (=IMPORTHTML(B3;"table";28)).

1/ i go to my server with this url http://myserver.com?url=https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xpar/nk/valuation
2/ Nodejs get the variable url
3/ Puppeteer go to the website and write the html version of the website on my server (index.html)
4/ i display this version on my server after 15 seconds

- i can't do the step 4. i don't know how i can force nodejs to display index.html after puppeteer write html version
- Is it possible to display the html version without writing on my server ?
- Do you know a faster way to **scrape** information from url like "https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xpar/nk/valuation" on google sheet ?

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();




// CAPTURE URL  /?url=https://google.com
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const{url} = req.query;
    if (!url || url.length === 0) {
        return res.json({error: 'url query parameter is required'});
    }
console.log(url);

run(url);

}
);


async function run(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
        
await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0})
  //  await page.goto('https://www.ebay.com/');
    await page.waitFor(15000);


const html = await page.content();
fs.writeFileSync("index.html", html);
    
//  await page.goto('about:blank')

return html;

page.close();
browser.close();
 //browser.disconnect();
   // await process.exit(0);
    //app.close();
server();   
};



function server() {

const html = await run(url);

router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

router.get('/about',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/about.html'));
});

router.get('/sitemap',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/sitemap.html'));
});

//add the router
app.use('/', router);
//app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

res.send(html);

}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

thanks

Comment: By "display", do you mean "send it back as reply to the client"? In case you do, you can simply `return html;` at the end of your `run` function, then `const html = await run(url);` in your route handler and finally `res.send(html);` or similar.

Comment: hello, by display i want to say : display the html page of morningstar on my server in return for the request "https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xpar/nk/valuation".

the goal is that my server serves as a proxy allowing to display the javascript page of morningstar in HTML

Comment: - i have to keep all the code or delete part ?
- i have to insert "const html = await run(url);" and res.send(html); in server function ? await need async function.

Comment: Yes, but you have an `async` function already: `async (req, res) ...`

Comment: thanks. i have modify the code but there is a problem with server function because is not async. have you test this code ?

Comment: I have modify the code in the first post. But there is an error

Comment: Here's code that works for me: https://pastebin.com/9uQTnqDf (turn off `headless` so I can see what's going on in puppeteer's chrome instance) - also no, scraping a page that is populated by JavaScript pretty much only works like that.

Comment: hanks a lot !!!! it's working with headless because it's on a server. I'm extremely grateful.

i have just this error (see answer below). Is it normal ?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap